# Clipping several raster datasets with mask?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, arcgis-10.3, masking

I would like to clip many images (raster datasets, input) with a mask (shapefile) for my study area. Is it possible to do with ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

I tried to merge all the images but it is too much for the computer (152 GB); that is why I was thinking in clipping the rasters directly.

Comment: Could you please supply more information on the format and type of raster data?

Comment: Hi, ok. the images I have are geodatabase raster dataset, 3 bands. Ortophotos. regards

Comment: and all the images have no coordenate systems (unknown)

Answer (score 3):

You want the Clip tool in the Data Management/Raster/Raster Processing toolset, and because you have multiple rasters it would be a good opportunity to use the Batch option with the tool.  Here's the way I like to deal with that interface:

1. right-click on the tool in the toolbox and choose Batch...
2. You see each tool instance as a row, with the columns being each input parameter.  Double click the "1" to the left of the first column to open the normal tool dialog for that instance.
3. Enter the "mask" shapefile as the output extent, and be sure to check "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry" to clip to feature boundaries in the shapefile.
4. Click OK, and with this first row highlighted, click the + on the right side of the interface.  Every new row (a.k.a. instance of the tool) will be prepopulated with the output extent that you already entered, and now you just have to add the input rasters.
5. When you run the batched tool, it just executes the tool instances one by one.

Comment: hi thanks. you mean to use the bacth option in the Clip tool ? http://webhelp.esri.com/%5Carcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/GP_3_8.htm  I tried but I can´t select what I want. I could only select shapefiles and these are single images/ortophotos

Comment: If you have the rasters in the table of contents, you can just drag them into the batch interface, into the first column of the first row, for example.  Or you can double click the "1" to the left of that column and use the normal dialog for finding rasters in your file directory.

Comment: ok, thanks, it works like that, just dragging them. I dont really need to clip the images (I just clip the data frame), but I will work better like that

Comment: Hi @prigual, if this worked for you, could you mark this answer as correct?  thanks!

Comment: hi. thanks but I still have a problem. I can drag all the images easily, but in the option clip features, ( I want a selected area that includes half of the images), I have to select one by one this option ...and I have 1340 images.  You know a better way, faster way to do that ? thanks

Comment: ok, well, 1,340 is a lot, so batching may not be your best option.  It may be worth learning a little bit of python to achieve this in the python console.  Nevertheless, understand that if you put the clipping features in the first row just how you want them, and then *highlight* that row before clicking +, the new rows that are created will be prefilled with anything in the highlighted row. Are all of your rasters in a single geodatabase?

Comment: yes, all the reaster all ina single geodatabase. Ill try later  or tomorrow what you say. too tired now of digitalizing, thanks

Comment: Hi. I am trying to do what you suggested.I use the batch option in the Clip, data management tool. . I enter the values for one image. After I highlight the first row and selecting the rest of images/rasters , I place them in the first row...but they are not prefilled  with the outpzut extent.  it should be possible to do that , no ?  thanks

Comment: Hi prigual, I'd like to help you further, but it won't work very well in this format.  Go to my [website](http://www.adamcfcox.com), and you'll see my e-mail address.  Send me an e-mail and we can get this figured out.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Clip tool in the Data Management toolbox in ArgGIS 10.3 allows you to clip rasters with a shapefile without having to use Extract by Mask.

Comment: hi, thanks. That would be good. But with the Clip Data Management tool, I can only select one raster and I would like to select many.  I tried to merge all raster/images together (new raster dataset) but it is too muxch information for the computer. regards

Answer (score 0):

You could build a tool in Model builder using what mr.adam has already stated. Load in the 'clip' tool and your shapefile and use the "Raster" Iterator to go through all of the rasters that are located in a single folder. This will get you the same end result as using the batch function without the need to specify each individual file.